# Do I need to learn OOP before learn Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have good knowledge of HTML CSS Bootstrap and Basic knowledge of Javascript & Jquery so do I need to clear all Object oriented programming before jump on Angular?

Comment: not necessary, but you need to be comfortable with javascript - this is important

Comment: Why not learn OOP while learning Angular JS? Also Angular JS does not have a very strong focus on OOP principals. I would use C# or Java /Ruby.. to learn OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should, but not just because of angular. For complex applications an Object oriented Structure is always a good decision, because it will help you to represent an subset of the reality in your application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :-)
Is there any website can resolve this for me?